# About how bean factory works

Tags: spring

I have a question about Spring on how the XmlBeanDefinitionReader and bean factory work together as a whole. I'm reading from the book Pro Spring 5 and come across the following code snippet.

```java
DefaultListableBeanFactory factory = new DefaultListableBeanFactory();
XmlBeanDefinitionReader rdr = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(factory);
rdr.loadBeanDefinitions(new ClassPathResource("spring/xml-bean-factory-config.xml"));
Oracle oracle = (Oracle) factory.getBean("oracle");
```

I have been trying to check the original Spring sources but still not so understand how it works. After creating the factory object, it is passed into the XmlBeanDefinitionReader. But how then can the factory object knows about the bean definition and can use the getBean method to get the bean?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. It knows about the beans because they're defined in the config file, and can use those definitions to instantiate beans. (With the caveat that beans can be defined in other ways as well.)

Comment: The read parses the xml file (that is what the `loadBeanDefinitions` does), the `BeanDefinition` (an interface in Spring) are handed to the `BeanFactory` which uses the `BeanDefinition` to create an instance of a bean. The `BeanDefinition` is the recipe on how to create a bean and the `BeanDefinition` can be read from xml, java or properties or whatever you decide to write to create `BeanDefinition`s.

Comment: I understand that the codes as a whole is to get the bean information from the config file. But want to how these two classes are related. The factory object is created and then passed to the XmlBeanDefinitionReader object, and then the reader loads the bean definition. It seems to me that the bean will be created from the XmlBeanDefinitionReader object. But instead it is getting from the factory object.